# Create directory using pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I want to save my log files locally under '/tmp/' under a new created folder '/new_folder/' So what i did is :

```
subdir = tmpdir.mkdir("new_folder")

subprocess.call("adb pull /SDcard/log/ {}".format(subdir), shell=True)
```

But the function fails with this error : TypeError: sequence item 5: expected string, LocalPath found

Could you please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Why don't you use pytest's tmpdir fixture? https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/tmpdir.html

Comment: I am using it , i did tmpdir.mkdir("") so he will create anothor folder under tmpdir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir` returns object of the type `py._path.local.LocalPath`. Convert it to string first like this:

```
subdir = tmpdir.mkdir("new_folder")
subprocess.call("adb pull /SDcard/log/ {}".format(str(subdir)), shell=True)
```